# How to append object field value as string in textarea on clicking particular object field using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to append object value to textarea on clicking on particular object field of ng-repeat. http://jsfiddle.net/kkd5nhev/

```
     <div ng-repeat="list in listing">
    <a href="">{{list.name}}</a>
    </div>
    <br>
```

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Main', function($scope){

```
$scope.listing = [{id :"1", name:"one"},{id :"2", name:"two"},{id :"3", name:"three"}];
$scope.complaint = "";
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to do the adding in your controller, for example:

```
$scope.addToTextArea = function(item) {
    var newline = String.fromCharCode(13, 10);
    $scope.complaint += item.name + newline;
}
```

and hook into this using the ng-click directive:

```
<a href="" ng-click="addToTextArea(list)">{{list.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make few changes

```
<a ng-click="append(list)">{{list.name}}</a>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.append=function(list){
        $scope.complaint +=list.name + ' ';
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually at one click its reflecting one name but i want to append every value. for eample: once i click on 'one' then it must reflect 'one' in tetarea, if i click on three it must reflect after 'one' like "one three" if i again click on one then o/p must be "one three one" in text area

Answer (score 0):

first bind it to an object

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Main', function($scope){

$scope.listing = [{id :"1", name:"one"},{id :"2", name:"two"},{id :"3", name:"three"}];
$scope.complaint = {};    
});
```

and in your html

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>

<div ng-controller="Main" >            

    <div ng-repeat="list in listing">
    <a href="" ng-click="complaint.val=list.name;">{{list.name}}</a>
    </div>

    <br>

    <textarea data="myModel" property="mail" placeholder="reflect name" ng-model='complaint.val'  ng-trim='false'></textarea>
```